# Vue Router does not redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am currently trying to only show pages, if the user is logged in. The problem I face is that `requireAuth()` seems to get called endless amount of times.

The code is use is:

```
// Routes
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Dashboard,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            requireAuth(to, from, next);
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardIndex
            }, {
                path: '*',
                name: '404',
                component: NotFound
            }
        ]
    },  {
        path: '/login',
        component: Login,
        name: 'login',
    },
];

function requireAuth (to, from, next) {
    if (!localStorage.token) {
        console.log('testing');
        next({
            path: '/login',
            query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
        })
    } else {
        next()
    }
}

// Routing logic
let router = new VueRouter({
    routes: routes,
    mode: 'hash'
});
```

`testing` is output ~1000 times before I receive the error:

> [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
>   warn @ app.js
>
> app.js RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

How can I make sure that `/login` is redirected to if `!localStorage.token`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this same issue as the respective error's source all boils down to `next()` function which is the required to navigate to the path which has `to.path` as value. If you'll use `router.push` or `router.replace` then possibility is to get called endless amount of times as callstack max error displays. So use simply `next()` and let `router` API do cumbersome work

I have done this type of thing, but in different manner. I handled all logic in `main.js` file. and `routes.js` file contains -

```
var routes = [{
  path:'/login', 
  component: Login
 },
 { 
  path:'/',
  component: dashboard
 }]
```

Now I have controlled all type of validation in main.js file using `vue-router` API as taking help from this - https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html

So now `main.js` would contain -

```
  const checkToken = () => {
    if(localStorage.getItem('token') == (null || undefined) ){
        console.log('token is not there : ' + localStorage.getItem('token'));
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true
    }
    }


//then Use `router.push('/login')` as

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.path == '/') {
    if(checkToken()) { 
        console.log('There is a token, resume. (' + to.path + ')' + 'localstorage token ' + localStorage.getItem("token"));
        next();

    } else {
        console.log('There is no token, redirect to login. (' + to.path + ')');
        router.push('/login');
    }
}
```

So you can structure like this as control all the things in `main.js` and leave `route.js` outta everything

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `localStorage` token present you are redirecting a user to `/login`.

Because this is also a a Vue route, your requireAuth logic will run again(because it runs for every route). Meaning you have just created a infinite loop where a user will constantly be redirected to `/login` even if a user is already on that page.

To stop this simply do not redirect to `/login` when you already are on `/login`.

I will leave that part to you but it shouldn't be that hard if you understand what is going on.